# pprint and ipdb in IPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pdb

I am trying to learn how to use the ipdb debugger. I inserted a breakpoint and by entering continue I advance from one breakpoint to another. If I want to print the value of the variable a  while I am half way in the execution between the two breakpoints, how can I do this with ipdb/pdb? I tried print and pprint but nothing showed up.
[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can use ***p*** or ***pp*** in IPDB console.

From [pdb documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

> **p expression**
>
> *Evaluate the expression in the current context and print its value.*
>
> **pp expression**
>
> *Like the p command, except the value of the expression is pretty-printed using the pprint module*

Comment: `pp`  is so useful `pp var`